# File process print last 2 character of first columns and rest

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have input file having 11 columns and this files need to process, output first columns last 2 digits and print rest of columns. Fields are  comma separated.  I have tried some commands but not get proper result.Need a shell script for this my file having more records

**input**

```
9303176179,989303176179,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9303138379,989303138379,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9302922849,989302922849,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9334284759,989334284759,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9334200459,989334200459,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9334022869,989334022869,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9334499819,989334499819,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9334036329,989334036329,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9303053859,989303053859,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
9302997519,989302997519,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
```

**Output Expected**

```
79,989303176179,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
79,989303138379,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
49,989302922849,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
59,989334284759,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
59,989334200459,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
69,989334022869,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
19,989334499819,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
29,989334036329,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
59,989303053859,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
19,989302997519,15335,A,1,9,1,0,201712091400,0,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what tools you have been trying, but I use `sed` for this sort of thing:

```
sed 's/^[^,]*\([^,][^,],.*$\)/\1/g'
```

You can use this as a filter (`sed ... <InFile >OutFile`) or use the `-i` option to update a file name which you would add to the run string (`sed -i ... InFile`).

This searches each line, looking for the last two characters before the first comma using `[^,]` to match any character except a comma. It then starts a match field before these two characters with `\(` and ends the match field at the end of line with `\)`. Then this match field replaces the whole match expression, which starts from start of line.

I habitually use Regular Expressions, so I find it straightforward to write this, but I'm the first to admit that they are difficult to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut` and `paste`:

```
paste -d, <(cut -f1 -d, input.csv | rev | cut -c1,2 | rev) \
          <(cut -f2- -d, input.csv)
```

As `cut` can't count the characters from the right, I used `rev` to revert each number in the first column, then extracted first two characters with `cut`, and reverted back.